# Why doesn't my code-behind execute?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to output the value of `x` in the following request: `http://localhost:4827/Default.aspx?x=123123`

I am getting no output at all.
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;

using MPads.Common;
using MPads.WebPatientPortal.Interfaces;
using MPads.WebPatientPortal.Presenters;
using MPads.BusinessLogic.Interfaces;
using MPads.Components.Interfaces;
using MPads.DataAccess;

using MPads.DataAccess.Interfaces;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace MPads.WebPatientPortal
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page, IDefault
    {


        private DefaultPresenter _presenter;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            _presenter = new DefaultPresenter();

            var fields = Request.QueryString;

            if (fields.Count > 0)
            {
                var x = Utilities.GetNvpValue(fields, "x").ToString();
                Trace.Write(x);
            }


        }


        public void loadAjaxContent(string content)
        {
            Page.RegisterStartupScript("myScript", " <script type=\"text/javascript\"> loadAjaxContent('" + content + "','POST',null); </script>");
        }

        public void DisplayMessage(string message)
        {
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Are you printing anything to the screen to show if it's firing??

Comment: use breakpoints in your page load event and see what happens

Comment: We will need to see the source of `var x = Utilities.GetNvpValue(fields, "x").ToString();` since that's what actually retrieves `x`. @PaulG, Accept Rates below 75% are generally low, at least by my standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Glimpse to find out this, here's the link [Glimpse-A client side Glimpse to your server](http://getglimpse.com/About/QuickStart)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have your even handler set up in your ASPX?

Assuming that you do: Consider instead of `Trace.Write();` using `Response.Write();`

`Trace.Write();` writes to a trace listener (which you can have display at the bottom of your page).

`Response.Write();` outputs text results directly to your page, not through a Trace Listener.